# How to save numpy masked array to file

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most efficient way of saving a numpy masked array? Unfortunately `numpy.save` doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.zeros((500, 500))
np.save('test', a)
```

This gives a:

```
NotImplementedError: Not implemented yet, sorry...
```

One way seems to be using pickle, but that unfortunately is not very efficient (huge file sizes), and not platform-independent. Also, [netcdf4](http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/) seems to work, but it has a large overhead just to save a simple array.

Anyone has had this problem before? I'm tempted just to do `numpy.save` of `array.data` and another for the mask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.zeros((500, 500))
a.dump('test')
```

then read it with

```
a = np.load('test')
```

Comment: Please note this is just a wrapper around pickle! [ref:numpy.ma.dump](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.dump.html#numpy.ma.dump)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it would be to save the data and mask of the masked array separately:

```
np.save('DIN_WOA09.npy',DIN_woa.data)

np.save('mask_WOA09.npy',DIN_woa.mask)
```

Then later, you can reconstruct the masked array from the data and mask.

Answer (score 2):

The [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877105/981499) is somewhat obsolete, and badly inefficient if the array being stored is sparse (it relies on uncompressed pickling of the array).

A better way to save/load a masked array would be to use an `npz` file:

```
import numpy as np

# Saving masked array 'arr':
np.savez_compressed('test.npz', data=arr.data, mask=arr.mask)

# Loading array back
with np.load('test.npz') as npz:
    arr = np.ma.MaskedArray(**npz)
```

Comment: Things tend to become obsolete almost a decade later...

Comment: @tiago hence my posting of an update :-) (I hope it didn't sound like I was criticising the previous answer: it was the best available at the time, just not any more)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed mask that doesn't need to be saved, then you can just save the valid values:

```
a = np.ma.MaskedArray(values,mask)
np.save('test', a.compressed())
```

You can then recover it doing something like:

```
compressed = np.load('test')
values = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=compressed.dtype)
np.place(values, ~mask, compressed)
a = np.ma.MaskedArray(values, mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving it inside a dictionary will allow you to keep its original format and mask without any trouble. Something like:

```
b={}
b['a'] = a
np.save('b', b)
```

should work fine.